# CORS headers for non-200 HTTP responses

Tags: security, http

I'm specifying an API for a REST service. The REST service will be primarily accessed by web browsers using XHR requests running code hosted from remote origins. Therefore, I'll need to add CORS support, such as the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header to allow for XSS.

Should I add CORS headers to non-200 responses, such as 400, 401 and 5xx?

Comment: Sorry if Software Engineering is not the right place (perhaps the reason for the downvote). I can't see a more appropriate StackExchange site. IMHO, SO is too implementation specific. Suggestions for another site welcome.

Comment: I don't know why this question has a down or close vote. It seems on-topic for this site.

Comment: SO dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38907385/should-non-2xx-status-code-responses-include-cors-specific-headers